# Soft wrap (white-space: pre-wrap) instead of horizontal scroll bars in code blocks

Tags: feature-request, markdown, code-formatting

I know [long lines are bad and all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104086/guidelines-for-code-editing-especially-horizontal-scrolling), but wouldn't they be better without the horizontal scroll bars?

Sort of related to [Why people do not split long lines when posting code here? - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41289/why-people-do-not-split-long-lines-when-posting-code-here). (The consensus seemed to be that people were lazy or didn't notice. But there are still some legitimate reasons to have lines over 80 chars or so.)

Answer (score 8):

Well, historically, [because IE7 didn't support it](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html) last time this was brought up made `pre-wrap` an immediate no-go, as it was a supported browser at the time.

But...even now, it doesn't really address the long un-broken line of code that a scrollable area does.  Pretty much, a lot of Java questions would have:

```
MyClassThatHandlesTheKeysTheCatAndTheCar.HeyCatNamedPicklesGoFindTheCarKeys(CarObjectWithKeyRemote petroleumPoweredManuallySteeredAutomobile1)
```

....that doesn't wrap correctly, but scroll bars handle it. ([Test it yourself!](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/bYnJD/2/))

Also, auto-wrapped code can be *much* uglier, especially when parameters and such can be manually spaced to fit the visible space in a much cleaner and more readable way.

Comment: -1 car1 is not a very good variable name, as it's not descriptive.

Comment: @balpha - so true, fixed!

Comment: Long lines without spaces should get split when adding `word-wrap: break-word`. Browsers like IE7 could still fall back to scroll bars.

Comment: @Lri - again this doesn't address the "way more readable when a *person* spaces it out appropriately" part...that's huge, us formatting code (or *attempting to*, rather) will never be as good as a human, especially with such a simple CSS approach in mind.  It's much better to leave it as-is, short of writing a formatting engine that handles every language...